# One bar stacked barplot

Tags: r, graph, plot

I can't seem to wrap my mind around the way R requires the data for a stacked barplot although I have search the net and the available resources.

I have the following data

```
    df<-c("III", "III", "I", "I", "I", "II", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"II", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "II", "I", "III", "II", 
"II", "III", "I", "II", "II", "I", "I", "IV", "I", "III", "I", 
"III", "I", "I", "II", "I", "II", "II", "I", "II", "I", "II", 
"II", "II", "II", "I", "I", "II", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"II", "II", "III", "I", "III", "I", "I", "I", "I", "II", "I", 
"II", "III", "I", "I", "I", "I", "III", "II", "II", "I", "I", 
"II", "I", "II", "III", "II", "III", "II", "III", "I", "III", 
"III")
```

I would like to create a single bar stacked barplot with the percentages of I, II, III, IV. I can only get R to do the following

```
barplot(table(df)*100/90, col=c("white", "gray70", "gray40", "black"), ylim=c(0,100))
```

Is there any way to make this a single bar stacked barplot? Please baseR solutions only.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will work for you but it wont look good

```
barplot(as.matrix(table(df)*100/90), 
        col=c("white", "gray70", "gray40", "black"), 
        ylim=c(0,100))
```

Comment: Thanks. It works very nice. What does as.matrix do that barplot understands as stacked graph?

Comment: It will convert data into 2-dimensions, which will be interpreted by barplot as multiple categories...

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using `ggplot`, which does not require numerical vector/matrix as input for a bar plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(df))+geom_bar(aes(x="df",fill=df),position="stack")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possibility (inspired by http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-add-marker-in-Stacked-bar-plot-td4635946.html):

```
df<-c("III", "III", "I", "I", "I", "II", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"II", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "II", "I", "III", "II", 
"II", "III", "I", "II", "II", "I", "I", "IV", "I", "III", "I", 
"III", "I", "I", "II", "I", "II", "II", "I", "II", "I", "II", 
"II", "II", "II", "I", "I", "II", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"II", "II", "III", "I", "III", "I", "I", "I", "I", "II", "I", 
"II", "III", "I", "I", "I", "I", "III", "II", "II", "I", "I", 
"II", "I", "II", "III", "II", "III", "II", "III", "I", "III", 
"III")

freq <- table(df)

df <- data.frame(names=names(freq), freq=as.vector(freq))

barplot(as.matrix(df[,2]), col=cm.colors(length(df[,2])), legend=df[,1], xlim=c(0,6), width=1)
```